# How to copy folders, subfolders, and file names without the actual content of the files?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I have dropbox on my phone and would like to copy my many ebooks and movies to dropbox so that when I'm at the used bookstore I can use my phone to see if I already have something or not. I don't have hundreds of gigabytes in dropbox, so is it possible to just copy the folders, subfolders, and file names but not their content?

Comment: I'd say you'd need to just copy a recursive directory listing to a text file and open it up to see if this will suffice. It'd probably be quicker than traversing a folder structure anyway.

Comment: This would mean run `DIR /S "C:\path\*.*" >> "C:\Path\List.txt"` from command prompt on Windows 7 and then when that's complete, open `C:\Path\List.txt` and see if that would work. If so, then this is the file to send to dropbox or automate for daily upload, etc. to dropbox. I'll add as an answer if this works for you after you test. This is a Windows Native solution.

Comment: Karen's Directory Printer is a nice software to save a folder structure to a text file (save to disk tab).   http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/karens_directory_printer.html

Comment: Another approach would be to just store shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

copy handler's copy/paste special is exactly what you want. it creates empty, place holder files with the same folder structure so you can browse through just like your real library

https://www.copyhandler.com

https://www.copyhandler.com/sites/default/files/screenshots/2016-03/taskedit.png

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.